# IE9 Assigning Different Value than IE Quirks Mode

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm using javascript to dynamically assign values to some html elements

```
var newInput = document.getElementById('newInput1');
var oldInput = document.getElementById('oldInput1');

newInput.value = oldInput.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

When I run this in IE Quirks Mode, my value is returned appropriately. My debugger will read:

```
Name      |  Value
newInput  |  777
```

however, in IE9 I'll sometimes get:

```
Name      |  Value
newInput  |  "\n   \n  777\n"
```

I haven't encountered this problem before; has `.firstChild` or `.nodeValue` been replaced in IE9?

**Edit**

I've noticed while assigning newInput.value, a single space `" "` is added to the string. This space is `.trim`med later in the code, but perhaps IE9 can't accept it at some point or another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
oldInput.firstChild.nodeValue.trim(); //to remove extra new line
```

The`trim()` method removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

Note: The `trim()` method does not change the original string.

[see this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

Comment: I just caught the white space being added into my string, thanks Niang I'll try this out